# My bootstrap does not work with new installation

Tags: javascript

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi8Cc.jpg)

```
 hi ,my bootstrap doesnot work yet ,because i am new user for bootstrap .
```

it doesnot work yet . anyone knows why ?
thank you

Comment: An image of your code [is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please, create [mcve].

Comment: If you don't provide details is impossible for anyone help you. What did you do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are going to do. The easiest way to make sure you code it right, download the bootstrap template and try to edit an element that you need.I do this when I first try to use Bootstrap as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should post your code here to assist you.
But I can simply suggest you to have a look at boostrap documentation.

Loading CSS, JS problems. 
I see your a screenshot. You need to add css file, js file in the folder you indicate.

You can use CDN links instead of them. You can find them in boostrap documentation.

If you add them, It will be working properly.

Good luck to you.